# Dell XPS 13 L321x cannot resume after suspend

Tags: suspend

I've a Dell XPS 13 L321x running Debian Jessie that cannot resume after being suspended.  Hibernate works fine if you trigger it with `pm-hibernate`.

I've tried `rmmod` on the `mei` and `mei_me` drivers suggested in https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=86241 but no effect.  I've similarly tried `rmmod` on the various wifi drivers linked to `iwlwifi` since https://askubuntu.com/questions/638835/xps-13-9343-failure-to-resume-from-suspend explained similar issues in much more recent XPS 13s, but again no effect.

I should probably actually blacklist these modules, or perhaps remove the wifi card itself.  I could try using a 4.3 kernel too.

How can I actually diagnose the problem with resume though?  Are there any ways to log the resume operation the way that suspend is logged?

I've found better information on suspend at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnderstandingSuspend and technique for debugging resume at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend although it does not work on my current kernel.

After playing around with single user mode suspend I feel confident the system simply does not detect the lid open event or key press events when suspended.  And hibernate works because initially it's powering-on like normal.  I suspect Linux is simply being too aggressive with the hardware that it deactivates when doing suspend.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any ways to log the resume operation the way that suspend is logged?

**Yes** `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` :D

Comment: It's kinda useless since it'll never be written to if suspend does not work.

Comment: Well, I understand, that suspend is working and resume is not working. It's suposed, that you can read all resume operations..... Did you try it?